# Delphi - Only the last item in array gets selected

Tags: arrays, multithreading, delphi

I am writing an application to allow the user to search for files, and then execute an operation which will copy these files to a new location.

A thread is launched to first search for the files, and then the results (as a stringlist) are added to a dynamic array of Tstringlist.This search can be performed as many times as required, and each subsequent time the array is expanded and the new stringlist of search results is added. This is done in the message loop as follows;

```
//definitions
fSearchThread: TSearchThread;
fFilesArray: array of TStringlist;

begin
  if Msg.Msg = WM_SEARCH_COMPLETED then
  begin
    fSearchThread.Terminate;
    SetLength (fFilesArray,Length(fFilesArray)+1);
    fFilesArray[High(fFilesArray)]:=fslSearchResults;
  end
end;
```

The method that is executed when the user wants to copy the files are as follows;

```
procedure TfMain.aGoExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  iArrayCount: integer;
  thFileCopyThread: TFileCopyThread;
begin
  for iArrayCount:=0 to (Length(fFilesArray)-1) do
  begin
    if fFilesArray[iArrayCount].Count > 0 then
    begin
      thFileCopyThread := TFileCopyThread.Create(false,self.Handle,C_LOG_FILE_NAME,
                            fFilesArray[iArrayCount],fslDestinationList);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The problem I am having here is that the function above only seems to work for the last stringlist in the array - i.e. the fFilesArray[iArrayCount] always seems to be pointing to the same stringlist in the array, and I can't work out why!

The result is that instead of the files in all of the stringlists in the array being copied, only the files in the last added stringlist actually gets copied.I can see that it is creating the right number of threads as per the length of the array, but the fFilesArray[iArrayCount] always points to the same stringlist.

Any help will be appreciated, I'm stumped!

Comment: Could it be that you are reusing the same TStringList instead of creating a new one every search? I can't tell because you left out that part of the code.

Comment: I guess you have a bug in your code. Please show an MCVE if you want us to help track it down.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue, but you do realize that the limits of the `for` loop are only evaluated once, before the loop is entered?

Comment: You're adding the same `fslSearchResults` instance to the array in your `for` loop, instead of creating a new instance of `TStringList` for every element you add to the array. Therefore, one stringlist exists that is being used over and over, and will only contain the last changes made. Your code needs to use `fFilesArray[High(fFilesArray)]:= TStringList.Create;` instead, and references to `fslSearchResults` need to change to `fFilesArray[Index]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the `fslSearchResults` gets cleared somewhere else in the code before the `fSearchThread` is executed every time (`fslSearchResults.Clear`). Would this still be a problem?

Comment: Yes. You're still going to end up with only the last operation's results in `fslSearchResults`, which is what you seem to be having an issue with here. I'm not sure quite what you intend: If the problem is that the `fFilesArray[iArrayCount]` always points to the same stringlist, and you're only using one stringlist (that you repeatedly clear), it seems like you're banging your head against the wall intentionally. If you want a separate stringlist for each thread, use a separate stringlist in each element of the array. If you only want to use one list, don't try to use it in multiple threads.

Comment: I don't understand why you are concealing the code from us. All you had to do was make that MCVE.

Comment: Hi David, I would like to post the whole code here but it's a very large with other irrelevant bits. What is a MVCE?

Answer (score 0):

@Ken that was spot on! I changed the code to the following;

```
if Msg.Msg = WM_SEARCH_COMPLETED then
begin
  fSearchThread.Terminate;
  SetLength (fFilesArray,Length(fFilesArray)+1);
  fFilesArray[High(fFilesArray)]:=TStringlist.Create;
  for j:=0 to fslSearchResults.Count-1 do
    fFilesArray[High(fFilesArray)].Add(fslSearchResults[j]);
  fslSearchResults.Free;
end
```

And it worked just as expected, I just create a fresh `fslSearchResults`whenever the search is started. I didn't realize that doing `fFilesArray[High(fFilesArray)]:=fslSearchResults;` didn't actually assign the contents of the stringlist to the new stringlist, but instead just became a pointer to the `fslSearchResults`(would this be the correct assumption?) I am new to using arrays, so this has been very helpful, thanks.

Comment: This isn't an issue with arrays, it's an issue with reference types and the meaning of the assignment operator